# array initializer must be an initializer list or wide string literal

Tags: c, gcc

I get this error when i try to compile and run, I'm completely new to programming I have no idea what to do please help me with this? i got this off a video and it looks like I've done exactly what he did but its not working heres the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CpG3oATGIs&t=6243s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getSum(int *array_val,int size)
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sum += array_val[i];
    }
    return sum;

}

int main()
{
    int my_array[5]=(10,20,30,40,50);
    int mySum = getSum(my_array,5);

    printf("the value of my sum is= %d",mySum);
}
```

Error message:

> error: array initializer must be an initializer list or wide string literal
>   int my_array[5]=(10,20,30,40,50);
>           ^

Comment: Wrong brackets.

Comment: int my_array[5]=(10,20,30,40,50); --> int my_array[5]={10,20,30,40,50};

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For initializations you need `{}` and not `()`.

The code will compile if you change your line as

```
int my_array[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
//OR
int my_array[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this statement:

```
int my_array[5]=(10,20,30,40,50);
```

The brackets are wrong.
Do this:

```
int my_array[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try    int my_array[5]={10,20,30,40,50};